# Pass a property from a class function

Tags: reactjs

So I moved from Vue.js to React. How can I create and use a function inside a component, that returns an `Array`, so I would pass it as a prop?

```
class Header extends Component {

 constructor(props) {
   ...
 }

 menuItems(){
    return [{title: 1}, {title: 2}, ...]
 }

 render(){
  return <Other 
    items={this.menuItems()}
  />
 }
}
```

A code like this results with a stack overflow. Probably because of the render that call the function.

In Vue, computed properties are easy and simple. what is the solution in React?

Comment: the above code doesn't look like creating a `stackoverflow` issue. You need to check other parts of code that is causing the issue. The way you have written to pass menu items looks ok.

Answer (score 0):

The method should return JSX code. Something like this can be a valid scenario:

```
import Menu from './Menu.jsx';
import MenuItem from './MenuItem.jsx';

const menuData = [{id:1, title: 1}, {id:2, title: 2}, ...];

class Header extends Component {    

  renderMenuItems(){
    return (
      menuData.map(item => (
        <MenuItem key={item.id} {...item} />
      )
     )
   }

   render(){
     return (
       <Menu>
         {this.renderMenuItems()}
       </Menu>
      )
   }
}
```